# Always appear in the aidl methods of stub class member variables of NullPointerException,But before that, it is not null .why?

Tags: java, android

This is my code,and in the `aidl`.

`mAccelUser` is null,but don't use aidl before,it is not null.

`mAccelUser`  is a `class member variables;`

```
private IXLAccelServiceEventListener.Stub listener = new IXLAccelServiceEventListener.Stub() {

   @Override
   public void onTimeCounterTimerTick(int total, int remain, boolean finish)
       throws RemoteException {
            XLAcceleratorImpl.this.onTimeCounterTimerTick(total, remain, finish);
        }
    @Override
    public void onTimeCounterTimerTick(int total, int remain, boolean finish) {

        if (finish) {
            //mAccelUser is null
            if (mAccelUser.mUserType == 2) {

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Its hard to understand the problem with the description given. You can put null check on mAccelUser to prevent nullPointerException. if(mAccelUser != null && mAccelUser.mUserType == 2)

Comment: stack:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.xunlei.common.accelerator.base.XLAccelUser.mUserType' on a null object reference
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
 at com.xunlei.common.accelerator.aidl.IXLAccelServiceEventListener$Stub$Proxy.onTimeCounterTimerTick(IXLAccelServiceEventListener.java:107)
 at com.xunlei.common.accelerator.impl.XLAccelService.onTimeCounterTimerTick(XLAccelService.java:411)